# JMETER 5.6.2 error when generating html report

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am blocked from generating the html report with jmeter at first it gave me the following error
[image]

I investigated and it said that the packages attribute was obsolete
[image]

So I took it out, when I try to generate the report now I get this error
ERROR StatusConsoleListener Error processing element GuiLogEvent ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
ERROR StatusConsoleListener Unable to locate appender "gui-log-event" for logger config "root"

[image]

I do not know what to do now :
I have java 8 and jmeter 5.6.2

I need to be able to generate the html report, any possible solution to obtain it

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is wrong, that is the main problem.

In order to run a test and generate HTML reporting dashboard you need to do something like:

```
jmeter -n -t "/path/to/testplan.jmx" -f -l "/path/to/result.jtl" -e -o "/path/to/dashboard"
```

if there are special characters in the path you need to surround the part of the path or the full path with quotation marks.

It looks like you miss a space between parameter and its value, fix it and you will be able to run your test.

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Dashboard generation after a load test](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_after_load_test)
- [JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)

---

- With regards to "StatusConsoleListener" warning - you seem to use some plugins which have still package scanning instead of [ServiceLoader](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/5885)
- With regards to "Could not open/create prefs" - you need to [run JMeter as Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/shell-experience/use-run-as-start-app-admin) once so it could create necessary registry keys

Comment: Thanks for responding regarding the commands, the same thing happens to me when I try to generate it from the GUI option of jmeter, the same error, as for the obsolete elements I understand that I must modify something in the log4j file but I don't know how to do it, there is somewhere where follow an example? Thanks in advanc

Comment: You're focusing on stuff which can be ignored and ignoring the important things which could be easily fixed.